# outlook 2007 ignoring cell padding

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have a table defined as

```
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25" width="600">
 <tr>
   <td width="160" bgcolor="#efefef">Text</td>
   <td width="340" bgcolor="#ffffff">Text</td>
 </tr>

</table>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><img src="image.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here for the image I have a gray shaded area of width 210px and the rest is white. 
Now this should get aliged with the first cell since it has width 160px + 50px (cellpadding) = 210px (in total)

However, outlook 2007 does not pick up this cellpadding. How can I get this to align in outlook 2007?

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @Quentin - validation isn't very helpful when dealing with email clients. Very few support valid HTML

Comment: The only way that i can get it to align in outlook 2007 is if i add a width of 210px for the cell and forget the padding.

Comment: @Cfreak — They have enough trouble with valid HTML. They have more trouble with invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I think your code should change

```
 <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25" width="600">
         <tr>
             <td width="160" bgcolor="#efefef">Text</td>
             <td width="340" bgcolor="#ffffff">Text</td>
        </tr>    
       </table>
  </td></tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><img src="image.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```